# Ledger Nano S+ error on CLI even after update

Tags: solana-cli, ledger-nano

I have checked the previous question on Ledger nano s+, and updated the cli to

`solana-cli 1.11.10 (src:843e018c; feat:4253057308)`

However, when I run

`solana-keygen pubkey usb://ledger?key=0`,

it shows

`zsh: no matches found: usb://ledger?key=0/0`

How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The question mark character is a special character in zsh. The below link has a couple recommendations of things you can try:

https://docs.solana.com/wallet-guide/hardware-wallets/ledger#keypair-url-parameters-are-ignored-in-zsh

Answer (score 0):

I checked with 1.11.10 and it works for me. Also, your error doesn't seem to be coming from Solana CLI/Ledger but from the shell itself. Try to add quotes around usb://ledger?key=0 and see if it helps.